# How to only have margin between child and not with parent in CSS?

Tags: html, css, parent-child, margin

This is my goal: have *no margin* between a *child* an a *parent*, and `25px` margin between *childs* in the *parent*. See explaining image:

[image]

I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

and this CSS:

```
#parent{
  width: 200px;
  height: 405px;
}

.child{
  width: 50px;
  height: 180px;
}
```

My question is: What is the best way to add the margin to every child?

I could do:

```
<div class="child" style="margin: 0px 25px 25px 0px"></div>
```

But then I have to do that to every child, and it gets harder when I have a lot of Children.

Comment: The solution to this is only possible if you have specific div(child) per row. Otherwise you need JS/JQuery for better and responsive solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 3 `div` childs in every row, then you can use:

```
#parent > div:not(:first-of-type):not(:nth-of-type(2)):not(:nth-of-type(3)){
    margin-top: 25px;  /* add margin-top to every div except the first 3 */       
}

#parent > div:nth-of-type(3n+2){
     /* add margin-left and margin-right to every second div in every row */
     margin-left: 25px;
     margin-right: 25px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ck5z5qxt/1)

Comment: This solution only works for the very specific case of having three children per row. I think the OP example was well just an example. It would be nice to have a more general solution.

Answer (score 5):

Try using `display: flex` for your parent div and `align` and `justify` your content with `space-between`.

Try it in the snippet:

```css
#parent{
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child{
    width: 50px;
    height: 180px;
    border: 1px solid lightcoral;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick example for you. If your width is fixed then this method will work. check here http://jsfiddle.net/91b2y94x/

```
    #parent{
  width: 423px;
  height: 370px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.child{
  width: 120px;
  height: 180px;
  background: Yellow;
  display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.child:nth-child(3n+3){
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would go with Vucko's answer, although Chris' feels a lot cleaner if you don't have to deal with old browsers.

This one is definitely **NOT** the best way to do it, but if for some reason the other options are impossible to use in your particular situation, this may be a way out.

You could use another div between parent and children with a negative margin:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="cheat">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And

```
#cheat{margin:-25px}
```

Again, this should not be done unless you absolutely have no alternative.